# how to put full background image for login image but not for further pages after login in angular 4/5

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to put background image for a login screen but i don't want this background screen after login (means background image shoud not display in further pages).

- For that i have created 2 containers i.e simple and full layout
  containers.
- login component is kept in simple layout and,
- home component is kept in full layout which contains app-nav, app-footer components.

so when i set bg-image for login that will continued with the next following pages.

so please help me out to set different backgrounds for different containers.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I've created two component's Login and full-layout. Inside your `app.module.ts` file put these lines of code below

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'loginpage', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'loginpage', component: LoginPageComponent },
{ path: 'full-layout', component: FullLayoutComponent },
{ path: '**', component: LoginPageComponent}
];
```

and import RouterModule & Routes from 
`import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';` also inside your `imports` array add this code `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)`

And I'm considering `AppComponent` will be your root container where you can put `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

And now inside your `login-component.html` put following code

```
<div
 style="background-image: url('../../assets/images/homepage_bgi.png'); background- 
 size: cover; height: 100% !important;">
 <button [routerLink]="['/full-layout']">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Here you go, background image won't be no more available on the lay-out page.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting background-image property to different values in login.component.css and home.component.css?

Comment: yeah, when i put some image for login component that will not fitted for full screen